# How to attach additional interfaces to an instance, post creation using Terraform in Openstack

Tags: openstack, terraform, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, terraform-provider-openstack

I am using Openstack Kilo and Terraform V 0.10
I need to attach multiple interfaces of same network to an instance.
I've tried the following attempts:

Adding network block three times in openstack_compute_instance_v2 using same network:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM`1" {
  name        = "VM1"
  count       = "1"
  image_name  = "image"
  flavor_name = "flavor"

  network = {
    uuid = "${openstack_networking_network_v2.NET_1.id}"
  }

  network = {
    uuid = "${openstack_networking_network_v2.NET_1.id}"
  }

  network = {
    uuid = "${openstack_networking_network_v2.NET_1.id}"
  }
}
```

Created three ports of same network and tried to add them in compute_instance:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM1" {
  name        = "VM1"
  count       = "1"
  image_name  = "image"
  flavor_name = "flavor"

  network = {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.port_1.id}"
  }

  network = {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.port_2.id}"
  }

  network = {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.port_3.id}"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately both did not work.
I am able to launch instance with single port.
Post creation I wanted to add additional interfaces.

Literally, I wanted to do the below post VM creation with single interface:

```
nova interface-attach --net-id $NET_1 "$VM1"
nova interface-attach --net-id $NET_1 "$VM1"
```